# base64 image file get corrupt while uploading to php server

Tags: php

Similar question has been asked previously but it didn't solve my problem so i am asking here again. Actually i am uploading base64 image file to php server and i have to save it there. I tried every suggested help but nothing works for me. my code

// here is my base64 code for image

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,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



    $src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD//gA7Q1JFQVRPUjogZ2QtanBlZyB2MS4wICh1c2luZyBJSkcgSlBFRyB2OTApLCBxdW...  ";
    // above the example of image base64 file

    // and server side code in php, i have posted base64 to php
    $img_part = explode(";base64,",$_POST['base64']);
    $img_type_aux = explode("image/",$img_part[0]);
    $ext = $img_type_aux[1];
    $image_base64 = base64_decode($img_part[1]);

    // i have tried all possible code like here $name = random_value+$ext
    file_put_contents($name,$image_base64); // didn't work then i used str_replace
    $image_base64 = str_replace(' ','+',$image_base64);
    file_put_contents($name,$image_base64); // i also didn't work
    $fp = fopen($name,"wb");
    fwrite($fp,$image_base64); // i also didn;t work
    fclose($fp);


please someone help me,
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this function This will work.

```
function convertBase64toimage($image_string){
$name='test_with_new_image.jpeg';
$folderPath=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/test/"; 
$img_part = explode(";base64,",$image_string);
$img_type_aux = explode("image/",$img_part[0]);
$ext = $img_type_aux[1];
$image_base64 = base64_decode($img_part[1]);
$file = $folderPath .$name;
file_put_contents($file,$image_base64); 
} 


$string='data:image/jpeg;base64,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';
$a=convertBase64toimage($string);
```

And output of the code 
[image]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188459/discussion-between-shubham-azad-and-rajesh).